Is there a proven exclusion script for Journey Builder that will delay emails over the weekend to the following Monday?
I have a basic journey in JB that sends a Thank You email for new subscribers. The email goes out within minutes of the subscriber signing up (within 5-10 minutes at most). I would like to DELAY these Thank You emails when the subscriber signs up on a Saturday or Sunday until the following Monday (since people don't generally check their emails on the weekends).
I've seen this question asked many times in the past 4-5 years on StackExchange, but I've never seen a formal, final answer. CoPilot suggested the below, but this isn't working. Any suggestions to edit the below, or an alternate script that definitely works? Thanks in advance.
%%[ 
SET @currentDate = NOW() 
SET @dayOfWeek = FORMAT(@currentDate, "dddd") 

IF @dayOfWeek == "Saturday" THEN 
 SET @sendDate = DateAdd(@currentDate, 2, "D") 
ELSEIF @dayOfWeek == "Sunday" THEN 
 SET @sendDate = DateAdd(@currentDate, 1, "D") 
ELSE 
 SET @sendDate = @currentDate 
ENDIF 

SET @formattedSendDate = FORMAT(@sendDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") 
IF @currentDate < @sendDate THEN 
 SET @deferFlag = "true" 
ELSE 
 SET @deferFlag = "false" 
ENDIF 
]%%


The short answer is no. An Exclusion Script is used to prevent an email from being sent, but it cannot be used to issue a delay.
Based on what you have provided, this is a welcome email which should ideally be sent as soon as someone subscribes. Delaying it until the next weekday (Monday) defeats the purpose of a welcome email.
If you don't want to send welcome emails on weekends, you would need to restrict subscriptions from being made on weekend days. However, it doesn't make sense either.

I am with Duc Le here on the evaluation-
People don't check their emails on weekends, but they do sign up on webforms to receive emails? Sure, but do you have statistics that point to this being worth additional effort (i.e. how many people do that, and how bad does that affect your welcome email KPIs) or is this a bit overengineered?  If these people receive the email Monday, is the email any worse? Maybe if it had a voucher inside that expires, but do people that do not read their emails redeem vouchers on weekends? Don't take this the wrong way please, just saying.
For the academic answer to your specific question (I am NOT recommending this for cost/benefit reasons): Sure it is possible, but you cannot do it with exclusion script alone. You have to separate the concept of a "delay" into the subtasks of blocking / sending later. Then you distribute blocking and sending across two processes.

Keep one journey that does real-time sends. That is Event-based. It can do blocking if weekend.

In this journey email, enter your exclusion script but just let it do the blocking if "today is not a weekday".
That is pretty much what you got from ChatGPT / coPilot.  Enter a "defer flag" or whatever, upsert it into a log data extension. What CoPilot doesn't tell you is that exclusion script needs to write true at the end, so that it actually excludes. see https://ampscript.guide/exclusion-scripts-syntax/
Temp result:
Your journey now only sends on weekdays (and then you worry about timezones etc.)

Set up a second journey based on an Automation, as you need something that is NOT event based but scheduled, to "send later".

An automation can run on a clock to send the deferred emails. Set the Automation up to select addresses with a "defer" flag in log. Let the automation trigger the journey. Schedule it to run Monday mornings (again: timezone) using the basic scheduler, and it will pick up the deferred emails from the weekend.
Result: Weekend signups get their email on Mondays. Profit?
